# Does there exist a natural number $m$ such that $\sigma^{(k)}((2m+1)^2)$ is an odd square number for all $k\ge 0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, divisors-multiples

This question, comes out of a [question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887562/a-collatz-like-function-or-eulers-totient-function-vs-the-sum-of-divisors) and I hope it is ok to ask it here:

**Does there exist a natural number $m$ such that $\sigma^{(k)}((2m+1)^2)$  is an odd square number for all $k\ge 0$?**

where $f^{(k)}$ denotes iteration of a function $f$ and $\sigma$ denotes the sum of divisors.

[Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNksFuwyAMhu99CqvVJCDpNnKclF125wWmqUINaVGJkxGiSXv6QSglqbRpHJD82_n826RRLRx7Y6T7JkhfNuCPVW6yCGoyyh6Gs_YJRnhB9pwyhvSpKgjf54iN-tRJXzR_HK_GY40e3VtCl6IWPaprB92CAD1CkKISjjFQw_vHLW77CZu19HXWRgH2DhA0xooMiJBHOQwKm2RoRfslh3XewZzYLTG3sRbLMWZWlBn_HMDCJfi0Ek-KCPpPq-gxd4ZWrWdDm0DHTOclf47n2mY3WI0uATrPrBgWfI6EjzrGqmXh9nUbS-OS9XgYPydpFYnvKygF6d8jRQ9VXfM8UGSIspVH11ufL1Nhkm6YPFGwkeQ7UnCTlKXL1V9F6Q9IPbLI&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) are some examples:

$m^2, \sigma(m^2)$

```
81 3^4 121 11^2
>
1476326929 7^2 * 11^2 * 499^2 1891467081 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 109^2
>
10994571025 5^2 * 67^2 * 313^2 13884144561 3^2 * 7^2 * 31^2 * 181^2
>
61436066769 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 120776405841 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 67^2
>
98551417041 3^6 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 151^2 190189315449 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 1093^2
>
119582481249 3^4 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 499^2 228867516801 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 19^2 * 109^2
>
141447449025 3^2 * 5^2 * 25073^2 253358202409 13^2 * 31^2 * 1249^2
>
220545762129 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 19^2 * 107^2 433950245001 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 127^2
>
388895668225 5^2 * 191^2 * 653^2 485512123369 7^2 * 13^4 * 19^2 * 31^2
>
619568914129 11^2 * 163^2 * 439^2 686781810729 3^2 * 7^2 * 19^2 * 31^2 * 67^2
>
890560253025 3^4 * 5^2 * 67^2 * 313^2 1679981491881 3^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 31^2 * 181^2
>
970952066161 7^2 * 11^2 * 67^2 * 191^2 1266928085241 3^2 * 7^4 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 31^2
>
2580138650961 3^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 * 499^2 3974915450961 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 67^2 * 109^2
>
3076652813521 7^2 * 83^2 * 3019^2 3623803369641 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 19^2 * 367^2
>
3739640454225 3^2 * 5^2 * 13^2 * 47^2 * 211^2 7445874636369 3^2 * 13^2 * 31^2 * 37^2 * 61^2
>
4138876942929 3^6 * 151^2 * 499^2 6259388523129 3^2 * 7^2 * 109^2 * 1093^2
>
4758545225281 19^2 * 29^2 * 37^2 * 107^2 5396129223849 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 67^2 * 127^2
>
9262289646801 3^2 * 19^2 * 107^2 * 499^2 14281891581321 3^2 * 7^2 * 13^2 * 109^2 * 127^2
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd be deeply surprised if the answer is yes. Iterates of $\sigma$ grows on average roughly exponentially or slightly faster, and squares a very sparse set, so hitting them repeatedly seems unlikely. I'd go further and actually conjecture that the almost exact opposite happens: For any fixed $m$ the sequence of $\sigma^n(m)$ will only have finitely many squares.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: That is what I also think and do not have a proof.